# Is there a solution for localizing "parameters/prompt" in SSRS 2008 R2 or 2012?

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I'm using now SQL Server 2008 R2.

My website shows the report exactly as it is, including the container where the parameters appear (the client prefers it that way).

However, my website solution includes localization (Portuguese, English, Spanish).

I've tried to translate the parameters by creating one parameter for each language, and then show them according the selected one. It didn't work in SSRS 2008. Because I don't know how to find the visibility properties of prompt.

Does anyone know a solution... Or if SQL Server 2012 has solutions for translating parameter's prompt, or conditional visibility?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I've found so far (SSRS 2008, 2008R2, 2010, 2012) is to break the DRY commandments, and duplicate the reports with language codes as part of the report name (e.g. MyReport_sp.rdl, MyReport_de.rdl, etc) and then place a web service between the client request and the SSRS instance.  The web service then has to field the request to the correct report based on a "Culture" parameter passed with the client's request.

This is NOT a good solution, though at least the Culture param is used in localizing the rest of the report as well.  We still have hopes that at some future date MS will add prompt localizability and we can rename the report to MyReport.rdl and just have everything actually localized.  Hmm, what a concept...

Answer (score 0):

There is none...
As per connect.microsoft.com, this feature has been requested after SSRS 2005 has been released, and while it is on Microsoft's TODO list, the programmer time to do this has never been allocated, and hence in 2012, SSRS is still not capable of doing that.

Although it's (with much effort) possible to translate everything else, it's not possible to translate the parameter prompt.

There is NO conditional visibility either, visibility of parameters is fixed.

Also, there is no way having SSRS use a supplied language instead of the one set in the browser language settings.

The only thing that you CAN do is write a C# program that loads your XML file, get's the report's parameter name(s) (and possibly the report's name as well), looks them up in a database, and automagically creates N reports for n languages.

Then, you have to redirect your users to the report in their language.
You then only need to write an upload tool, because you won't want to do that by hand.

The other way is to use the ReportViewer control, and re-implement parameter selection.
I think there's CrissCross that tries to do that, but it failed in all but 2 of the reports that I tested.

An evil hack would be:

```
parametername: babla_language1 / blabla_language2 / blabla_language3 / blabla_language4
```

and then use jQuery to get that string. do string.split('/')[index_of_language]

and then prey that / is never within "blabla_languageXY"

**Edit:**
I actually did that. You have to use setInterval to do it, because there is no way to detect change when you select a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround would be to just put a number in the prompt for the parameter then prefix the label of each parameter with the localised version by either using "get values from query" or by using the expression builder with a switch statement in the label expression.

For the get values from query option you would have a dataset something like this if you have the translated versions in the query:

```
SELECT ParamLabel, ParamValue
FROM MyLocalisedParameters
WHERE UserLanguage = @Language
```

Or like this if not:

```
SELECT
    CASE @Language
        WHEN 'pt-PT' THEN 'Selecione Departamento: ' + ParamLabel
        WHEN 'es-ES' THEN 'Seleccionar Departamento: ' + ParamLabel
        ELSE 'Select Department: '  + ParamLabel
    END AS ParamLabel
    , ParamValue
FROM MyParametersTable
```

in both cases creating and assigning the Globals!Language to a Parameter called @Language.

Or if using the expression builder for a hardcoded set of values it would look something like this:

[image]

either way the end result would look something like this:

[image]

Not perfect but functioning and easier to maintain than several copies of the same report.
If you want it to look a bit tidier then just have the Parameter prompt as only one entry in the parameters list and set it to the default value to avoid repetition on every line.